# Favicon not Appearing - Nodejs Express on Ubuntu

Tags: favicon

I put `favicon.ico` in my app's root.  I do not have any `<link>` tags in my html regarding favicon.  My understanding is that by default, browsers (I'm using Chrome) will load and show `favicon.ico` if it is in the default folder.  No luck.

I have also tried `<link>` tags in my html.  I tried generating several files for multiple browser/device support, with `<link>` tags, as instructed here:  https://realfavicongenerator.net/  (I put the `<link>` tags in my layout view.)  No luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Things you might want to check:

- Browse your site with Chrome or Firefox and check the dev console: do you see 404 errors? (eg. your images are not in the right directory).
- Browse your site with a browser you normally don't use. Favicon caching issue is a classic: your regular browser might not reload your new favicon immediately.
- Run the [checker](https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker). It might give you additional information (note : I'm the author of RealFaviconGenerator).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and of course, for the tools you provide, too.  I ran the checker, and all of the tests fail because the files are absent.  I have a domain, superdocs.com.  I created a subdomain, basketball.superdocs.com.  In c-panel, I point the subdomain to my server's IP address, 107.213.240.37.  My server is Ubuntu.  The app is located and runs at the folder, /opt/Basketball.  I run a directory list, and all the files (including favicon.ico) appear.  On your checker, whether I check basketball.superdocs.com or 107.213.240.37, the checker says the files are absent.

Comment: basketball.superdocs.com/users/login works but basketball.superdocs.com/apple-icon-60x60.png does not. Can you spot the difference between these two items? As a workaround, you might want to put the favicon files under a subdirectory, if you feel like the root folder might be the cause of the issue.

Comment: RealFaviconGenerator was really helpful, Thanks

Comment: @adamwest Great! Thanks :)